# Track Adwords client after command validation

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

My problem today is the following :

I want to track conversion for the purchases on my website, coming from Adwords.
But I want to push the conversion information via the conversion tracking tag, when I validate the command from my admin. So there I'm wondering, how can I know at the moment, when I validate the command in my admin, if the command correspond to a client comming from Adwords, and who ?

Thank you for your help, I hope it's clear for you to understand.

Fred

Answer (score 0):

You should use "offline conversion tracking".

First you save the GCLID from the URL and then you send it to Google Ads. The problem is that you are going to lose the multidevice conversion tracking...

[Google Ads offline conversion tracking](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/2998031?hl=en)